# Calculating the calendar week in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using the following formula to calculate the calendar week if referenced to a cell with date:

```
=INT((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1);1;1)-WEEKDAY(A1))/7)+2
```

but it does not work properly. If I enter `24.08.2012` I get calendar week 35 but it is actually 34.

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the formula above only works with US dates, since the first calendar week always starts on the 1st of January. In Europe it's different (in VB terminology: first four days).

In VBA it can be done like this:

```
Format(datefield, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
```

Excel 2010 comes with a built-in function for the calendar week.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will give you the ISO week number [where week 1 of each year starts on the first Monday on or after 29th December, and every week has 7 days]

`=INT((A1-WEEKDAY(A1;2)-DATE(YEAR(A1+4-WEEKDAY(A1;2));1;4))/7)+2`

as Andreas says in Excel 2010 you can get the same with WEEKNUM function using

`=WEEKNUM(A1;21)`

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2007 `=WEEKNUM(A1,1)` and  `=WEEKNUM(A1)` return `34` whereas `=WEEKNUM(A1,2)` returns `35`, when `A1` is 24.08.12 (see [Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/weeknumber.htm)).

Answer (score -1):

Your formula gave me an error with the semicolons when picking the date and the year. Instead has to use commas. Also, I don't know if you have specific formatting on A1, but 24.8.2012 is by default in Excel 2013 not a valid date. However, your formula works on a new Excel workbook after changing the date format and the commas.

`=INT((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)-WEEKDAY(A1))/7)+2`

[image]

Comment: This happens if you use the german version. You have to replace "," with ";" otherwise you get an error. Not sure if this is the reason the formula fails.

Comment: UDF works: http://www.rondebruin.nl/weeknumber.htm